# How to run "gg=G" on several files?

Tags: shell, vim, indentation

In vim, `gg=G` does a great job re-indenting your current file and I'd like to do that on several files.

I would like to do something like this:

```
files=`find $1 -type f`
for file in $files
do
    vim -e -s -n "+gg=G|wq" $file
done
```

The problem is that `gg=G` is not a command (if you type `:gg=G` in vim, it throws an error), so it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

I think I found it! (of course 10 minutes after I posted the question, even though I searched before for 4 hours)

```
files=`find $1 -type f`
for file in $files
do
    vim -e -s -n "+normal gg=GZZ" $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the files you want to modify in vim

```
vim *
```

Then use `:bufdo` to execute a command in all loaded buffers

```
:bufdo normal 0=G
```

Finally, save all files and exit

```
:wqa
```